# How to divide this Python code into different functions?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm making a code that, starting from an xml file:

- stores the index of child elements of a tag and the child elements as key, values in a dictionary;
- deletes keys whose values contain a certain string;
- joins the dict values and extracts their text;
- replaces certain values with "";
- counts the occurrences of specific regex I specify.

Everything works fine, I just don't really know how to put these steps into working functions, as I tried and I can't make the return values taken from other functions. How to make my code more neat?

Here is my code that works but is not neat at all:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import re

project_path = "output2.xml"
item_group_tag = "new_line"
cl_compile_tag = "text"

mydict = {}

def main():
    tree = minidom.parse(project_path)
    item_group_nodes = tree.getElementsByTagName(item_group_tag)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        #print("{} {} ------------------".format(item_group_tag, idx))
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(cl_compile_tag)
        for cl_compile_node in cl_compile_nodes:
            #print("\t{}".format(cl_compile_node.toxml()))
            mydict[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

listakey = []

def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                #return k
                print(k)
                listakey.append(k)
    return None

#Checking if string 'Mary' exists in dictionary value
print(search(mydict, '10.238')) #prints firstName
#print(listakey)

for x in listakey:
    del mydict[x]

mylist = []
uncinata1 = " < "
uncinata2 = " >"
punto = "."
virgola = ","
puntoevirgola = ";"
dash ="-"
puntoesclamativo ="!"
duepunti = ":"
apostrofo ="’"
puntointerrogativo = "?"
angolate ="<>"


#print(mydict.values())
for value in mydict.values():
    myxml = ' '.join(value)
    #print(myxml)
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
    lista = ([text.text for text in tree.findall('text')])
    testo = (' '.join(lista))
    testo = testo.replace(uncinata1, "")
    testo = testo.replace(uncinata2, "")
    testo = testo.replace(punto, "")
    testo = testo.replace(virgola, "")
    testo = testo.replace(puntoevirgola, "")
    testo = testo.replace(dash, "")
    testo = testo.replace(puntoesclamativo, "")
    testo = testo.replace(duepunti, "")
    testo = testo.replace(apostrofo, "")
    testo = testo.replace(puntointerrogativo, "")
    testo = testo.replace(angolate, "")
    print(testo)

    find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
    find_fase_base = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")# ] AN parole da cui T
    find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT") #] parole → T
    find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
    find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])") #] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
    find_fase_12_leo = re.compile(r"(?!.*da cui)\]\s+AN\s1\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+2\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)")#] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole escludendo da cui dopo
    find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T") # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole parola da cui T
    matches_prima = re.findall(find_prima, testo)
    matches_fb2 = re.findall(find_fase_12, testo)
    lunghezza = len(matches_fb2)
    mylist.append(lunghezza)


count = 0
for elem in mylist:
    count += elem

print(count)
```

The final goal would be to create a count function for each regex I specify.

EDIT:
sample XML file:

```
<pages>
  <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
    <textbox id="0" bbox="191.745,592.218,249.042,603.578">
<textline>
     <new_line>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="297.284,540.828,300.188,553.310" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">della quale non conosce che una parte;] </text>
              <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="322.455,540.839,328.251,553.566" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">prima</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="331.206,545.345,334.683,552.834" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="7.489">1</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="177.602,528.028,180.850,540.510" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">che nonconosce ancora appieno;</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="189.430,532.545,192.908,540.034" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="7.489">2</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="203.879,528.028,208.975,540.510" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">che</text>
            </new_line>
</textline>
</textbox>
</page>
</pages>
```

I want just to return the count of the regex I specified.

Comment: Welcome to CR. Can you attach a sample xml file and show expected results ?

Comment: Done, see update, let me know if it helps

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, welcome to CR and Python world. Let's start from the beginning.

#### [Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

In Python, the imports are usually put at the top:

```py
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
```

#### Functions

You created some functions which you might want to group together:

```py
def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                #return k
                print(k)
                listakey.append(k)
    return None


def main():
    tree = minidom.parse(project_path)
    item_group_nodes = tree.getElementsByTagName(item_group_tag)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        #print("{} {} ------------------".format(item_group_tag, idx))
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(cl_compile_tag)
        for cl_compile_node in cl_compile_nodes:
            #print("\t{}".format(cl_compile_node.toxml()))
            mydict[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
```

Let's first improve these functions.

#### `search`

In this function it looks like you're creating a new list which contains items that contain a specific `value` in `values`s ... values. The naming of your variables and function are both confusing and don't stick to the [recommended styling conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34).

```py
def filter_values_by_keyword(my_dict, filter_by):
    """
    Return a list of values which contains `filter_by` keyword.
    
    Arguments:
        my_dict (dict): Dict containing (...data specifics here)
        filter_by (str): Keyword to look for in values of my_dict
        
    Return:
        List of filtered values
    """
    return [value for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by in value]
```

Now this is how I would reimplement your `search` function. As you can see, you can now figure out what the function is doing only by looking at its name and parameters. If that's not enough, I've added a docstring to better describe what the function does.

#### `main`

Now, this doesn't look like a proper `main` function. The `main()` function of a program *usually* contains all the logic within a program ... which is not happening here. It looks like you're just parsing a xml file and add some specific data to a dictionary. Let's rename our function and add some improvements to it.

```py
def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path, tag_name_1, tag_name_2):
    data = {}
    xml_tree = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_group_nodes = xml_tree.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_1)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_2)
        for _ in cl_compile_nodes:
            data[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
    return data
```

Now it's a bit better. We're generating a dictionary from an XML by looking after specific tag names. You can add docstrings to this to make the functionality even more clearer.

Now that you've moved the non-main logic into a proper function, let's add all the remaining lines into a proper main function:

```py
def main():
    data = get_xml_by_tag_names('output2.xml', 'new_line', 'text')
    filtered_values = filter_values_by_keyword(data, '10.238')
    for item in filtered_values:
        del data[item]

    mylist = []
    uncinata1 = " < "
    uncinata2 = " >"
    punto = "."
    virgola = ","
    puntoevirgola = ";"
    dash = "-"
    puntoesclamativo = "!"
    duepunti = ":"
    apostrofo = "’"
    puntointerrogativo = "?"
    angolate = "<>"

    for value in data.values():
        myxml = ' '.join(value)
        # print(myxml)

        tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
        lista = ([text.text for text in tree.findall('text')])
        testo = (' '.join(lista))
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata1, "")
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata2, "")
        testo = testo.replace(punto, "")
        testo = testo.replace(virgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoevirgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(dash, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoesclamativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(duepunti, "")
        testo = testo.replace(apostrofo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntointerrogativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(angolate, "")
        print(testo)

        find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
        find_fase_base = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] AN parole da cui T
        find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT")  # ] parole → T
        find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
        find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
        find_fase_12_leo = re.compile(
            r"(?!.*da cui)\]\s+AN\s1\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+2\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole escludendo da cui dopo
        find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(
            r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole parola da cui T
        matches_prima = re.findall(find_prima, testo)
        matches_fb2 = re.findall(find_fase_12, testo)
        lunghezza = len(matches_fb2)
        mylist.append(lunghezza)

    count = 0
    for elem in mylist:
        count += elem

    print(count)
```

This `main()` function can be also refactored quite a bit but unfortunately I don't have enough time at the moment. Here's the full code for my proposed changes:

````py
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def filter_values_by_keyword(my_dict, filter_by):
    """
    Return a list of values which contains `filter_by` keyword.

    Arguments:
        my_dict (dict): Dict containing (...data specifics here)
        filter_by (str): Keyword to look for in values of my_dict

    Return:
        List of filtered values
    """
    return [value for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by in value]


def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path, tag_name_1, tag_name_2):
    """
    Your docstring here.
    """
    data = {}
    xml_tree = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_group_nodes = xml_tree.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_1)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_2)
        for _ in cl_compile_nodes:
            data[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
    return data


def main():
    data = get_xml_by_tag_names('output2.xml', 'new_line', 'text')
    
    filtered_values = filter_values_by_keyword(data, '10.238')
    for item in filtered_values:
        del data[item]

    mylist = []
    uncinata1 = " < "
    uncinata2 = " >"
    punto = "."
    virgola = ","
    puntoevirgola = ";"
    dash = "-"
    puntoesclamativo = "!"
    duepunti = ":"
    apostrofo = "’"
    puntointerrogativo = "?"
    angolate = "<>"

    for value in data.values():
        myxml = ' '.join(value)
        # print(myxml)

        tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
        lista = ([text.text for text in tree.findall('text')])
        testo = (' '.join(lista))
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata1, "")
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata2, "")
        testo = testo.replace(punto, "")
        testo = testo.replace(virgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoevirgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(dash, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoesclamativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(duepunti, "")
        testo = testo.replace(apostrofo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntointerrogativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(angolate, "")
        print(testo)

        find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
        find_fase_base = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] AN parole da cui T
        find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT")  # ] parole → T
        find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
        find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
        find_fase_12_leo = re.compile(
            r"(?!.*da cui)\]\s+AN\s1\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+2\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole escludendo da cui dopo
        find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(
            r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole parola da cui T
        matches_prima = re.findall(find_prima, testo)
        matches_fb2 = re.findall(find_fase_12, testo)
        lunghezza = len(matches_fb2)
        mylist.append(lunghezza)

    count = 0
    for elem in mylist:
        count += elem

    print(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

```
````

Comment: Thank you, it just now doesn't work the deletion of the item if the value of the dict contains "10.238"...

Comment: I want to delete the whole dict entry if there is that value, I mean